# How to catch 'missingtitle' error for media_wiki gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mediawiki

I am working rails framework. I am using 'media_wiki' gem. I wish to catch the 'missingtitle' error. See below

```
mw = MediaWiki::Gateway.new('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/')
wiki_content = mw.render('msadb')
```

It led to an error

```
MediaWiki::APIError: MediaWiki::APIError: API error: code 'missingtitle', info 'The page you specified doesn't exist'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mediawiki-gateway-0.5.0/lib/media_wiki/gateway.rb:711:in `get_response'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mediawiki-gateway-0.5.0/lib/media_wiki/gateway.rb:669:in `block in make_api_request'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:228:in `call'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:228:in `process_result'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:178:in `block in transmit'
from /home/papri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:72:in `post'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mediawiki-gateway-0.5.0/lib/media_wiki/gateway.rb:692:in `http_send'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mediawiki-gateway-0.5.0/lib/media_wiki/gateway.rb:661:in `make_api_request'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mediawiki-gateway-0.5.0/lib/media_wiki/gateway.rb:106:in `render'
from (irb):18
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/papri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

And when i tried to catch this error using **rescue begin loop**, it didnt work.

```
mw = MediaWiki::Gateway.new('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/')
begin
wiki_content = mw.render('msadb')
rescue
print "This is a missing title error"
end
```

The output was the same error as before. Rescue begin were not able to catch this error. How should i catch this error.

Comment: If you look at the actual page in the browser, you can see it is an error: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/.

Comment: @RyanBigg AFAIU the question has nothing to do with `MediaWiki`, it stated for “why rescue does not rescue”.

Comment: He wouldn't NEED to rescue if he was making a valid API request!

Answer (score 0):

`MediaWiki::APIError` is not a `StandardError` descendant, that’s why it’s not catched by default `rescue` statement ([See](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html): “If you write a rescue clause with no parameter list, the parameter defaults to StandardError.”)

So, you need to specify `MediaWiki::APIError` in rescue clause explicitly:

```
mw = MediaWiki::Gateway.new('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/')
begin
  wiki_content = mw.render('msadb')
rescue MediaWiki::APIError => e
  print "This is a missing title error"
end

# ⇒ This is a missing title error => nil
```